# Doctrine querybuilder get entities from many-to-many relation

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony, query-builder

I have a `Project` entity. A Project can have multiple `User` entities. Also, a `User` entity can have many `Project` entities. Therefore, there is a many-to-many relation between the two.

Now I want to get all users (participants) from a single project. The `Project` entity has a reference like this to the User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Users\User", inversedBy="participating_projects")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="projects_users")
 */
private $project_participants;
```

The User entity has a reference like this to the Project entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Projects\Project", mappedBy="project_participants")
 */
private $participating_projects;
```

Im trying to do the following with querybuilder:

```
$qb = $entity_manager->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('p', 'pp')
    ->from('AppBundle:Projects\Project', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('p.project_participants', 'pp')
    ->where('p.id = :project')
    ->setParameter(':project', $project->getId())
    ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

The problem here is that I have to also select 'p', but I only want to have 'pp'. Anyone has an idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the users from related project instead:

```
$qb = $entity_manager->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('u', 'pp')
    ->from(User::class, 'u')
    ->innerJoin('u.participating_projects', 'pp')
    ->where('pp.id = :project')
    ->setParameter(':project', $project->getId())
    ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```